Synchronizing a game for 4 players on a website
I have tried to synchronize my game in the "jungle professor board" folder using the user accounts people will create on the website but can't seem to work.
It's a four player game I have designed for my customer but I am struggling with the problem of synchronization.
Could someone please help me sync using WebSocket or any other method? Is there any template code that people use to sync games using WebSocket or other platforms?
The files are on this link below
https://github.com/FrankKangire/jungleprofessor
I tried using WebSocket in node but have failed. I am stuck and I don't know how other websites do it
